# Conditional result from query based on column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm working on simple queries but can't figure out how to modify to produce the below output.

```
  Number Name Flag
  1      ABC   NULL
  1      DEF   FG
  1      DEF   NULL
```

I need to produce this output:

```
  Number Name Flag
  1      ABC   NULL
  1      DEF   FG
```

The logic is when Number and Name are same, take the rows with the Flag.

Comment: What happens if you have another row containing `1 DEF GH`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

First some test data:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Number INT,Name VARCHAR(10),Flag VARCHAR(3))

INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES
    (1,'ABC',NULL),
    (1,'DEF','FG'),
    (1,'DEF',NULL)
```

The the query like this:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Flag DESC) AS iRank,
        tbl.Number,
        tbl.Name,
        tbl.Flag
    FROM
        @tbl AS tbl
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    CTE
WHERE
    CTE.iRank=1
```

Comment: Perfect !!! That worked the best for the scenario , I was looking for .. Thanks !!!!

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way, but I don't know if that meets your requirements if there is more than one non-NULL value.

```
SELECT Number, Name, Flag = MAX(Flag)
  FROM dbo.Table
  GROUP BY Number, Name;
```